# Word for "taking advantage of non-public resource"?

Tags: vocabulary

One is always sleepy at the afternoon, especially after a full lunch. I just had a good doze in a lovely sofa after some reading in a hotel nearby, used the toilet , enjoyed the music, and read the newspaper.

Is there an English word for ppl like me taking advantages of hotels or similar non-public places? :p by non-public I mean, it's ok to go to public places such as public gardens, as we pay the tax, right...

Comment: Parasitising perhaps :D

Comment: Under English common law, which has been influential in legal development across the English-speaking world, and elsewhere, trespassing is not a criminal offence. The only remedy for a landowner against a trespasser is to evict them in a reasonable manner. Hence, since you are not actually breaking any law, you perhaps see what you are doing as a right. I guess you could, however, be sued for the theft of soap or toilet paper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *freeloader* is someone who exploits opportunities to get things for free. It can refer to any resource, such as time or space, but is most commonly applied to food, drink, and intoxicants.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Jon that freeloader would probably be the most common term, particularly in the US.

The literal definition of ["scrounger"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrounger) in the international English world would also qualify:

> informal , derogatory A person who borrows from or lives off others

and a similar, more peculiarly Australian term is ["Bludger"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bludger?searchDictCode=all).

Though it's worth noting that in the US the term ["scrounger"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/scrounger) also has a less derogatory meaning:

> A cleverly resourceful person who finds and procures items for a
>   specific purpose

I suspect that this secondary meaning probably stems from the role of a "scrounger" in POW camps during WW II. I've seen the term used in a number of history books which I don't have references to at the moment, but you can refer to, for instance, James Garner's character in the movie *The Great Escape*. Because of that dual meaning I'd probably be inclined to go more for "freeloader" which is universally understood and is universally negative, though in my own patch of Australia I suspect that "bludger" would be more commonly used.

As Tanninah noted "parasite" is another possibility, "advantage taker" is another term that I've heard used (but it's clumsier and obviously less concise than a single word), and in politics down here another expression has gained some currency recently; ["lifters and leaners"](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/if-were-not-lifters-its-because-society-forces-us-to-be-leaners-20140702-zstli.html) with "leaners" being the type of people who take advantage of the work of others in the way described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "freeloader" the term "parasite" is certainly appropriate.

You can find other synonyms here http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/parasite if you prefer some more colorful terms. :)